# best way to use .unshift in react to push variables in a state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently working on an app where on a particular page users can comment, and after the comment, their comment is supposed to be the one on top. I'm currently using the below script but when I execute the post is able to send to the server but the view doesn't change

CONTAINER COMPONENT

```
commentPost = () => {
  const api = create({
    baseURL: "baseurl.com/api",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      header1: this.state.communityID,
      header2: userID
    }
  });
  const self = this;
  self.setState({ showCommentLoader: true });
  api
    .post(
      "newItems/" +
        `${this.state.groupID}` +
        "/members/" +
        `${userID}` +
        "/posts/" +
        `${this.state.postID}` +
        "/comments",
      {
        text: this.state.newComment
      }
    )
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      self.setState({ showCommentLoader: false });

      //updating the state
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        postComments: prevState.postComments.map(el => {
          return {
            ...el,
            text: this.state.comment,
            likesCount: 0
          };
          return el;
        })
      }));
    });
};
```

VIEW

```
<View>
  <Text
    style={{
      paddingLeft: 10,
      fontSize: 16,
      color: "#4a4a4a",
      fontFamily: "HelveticaNeue-Light"
    }}
  >
    {item.text}
  </Text>
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => checkLikeDisLike(item)}
    style={{
      alignSelf: "flex-start",
      position: "relative",
      top: 5,
      paddingLeft: 10
    }}
  >
    <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}>
      {item.likesCount}
      {"\n"}
    </Text>
    <Icon name="md-thumbs-up" type="ionicon" />
  </TouchableOpacity>

  <TouchableOpacity
    style={{
      alignSelf: "flex-end",
      position: "relative",
      top: -20,
      paddingRight: 5,
      paddingBottom: 20
    }}
  >
    <Icon name="ios-chatboxes" type="ionicon" color="#517fa4" />
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

What can I do to display the comment after it's been posted to the server, just like in native javascript you can do `unshift`

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks like you don't need `self` just call `this.setState` directly.

But setState is not changing because you are setting state using your old array reference. use this to copy your array to a new variable `var newArray = oldArray.slice();`and then set it to state.

Something like this:

However I am not checking your mapping,

```
const newArray = this.state.postComments.slice();
// do your mapping changes here
this.setState({postComments: newArray});
```

Comment: i'm not getting it, can you phrase it into my code?